# How to iterate all "public string" properties in a .net class

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Lets say I have some random .cs file containing a class with some properties and methods of all sorts.

How can I iterate the names (as strings) of all these public string properties?

Example.cs:

```
Public class Example
{
 public string FieldA {get;set;}
 public string FieldB {get;set;}
 private string Message1 {get;set;}
 public int someInt {get;set;}

 public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   Message1 = "Fields: ";
   ForEach(string propertyName in this.GetPublicStringProperties())
   {
     Message1 += propertyName + ",";
   } 
   // Message1 = "Fields: Field1,Field2"
 }

 private string[] GetPublicStringProperties()
 {
    //What do we put here to return {"Field1", "Field2"} ?
 }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
private string[] GetPublicStringProperties()
{
    return this.GetType()
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        .Select(pi => pi.Name)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Same as above: how to include a check on string properties? I dont want to get someInt in my example.

Comment: Updated with typeof(string) check.

Comment: Oh, there's a "PropertyType".. ofcourse :-) thanks for the complete solution.

Comment: I would not necessarily do the `== typeof(string)` check. It will work fine here, because `System.String` is `sealed`. But in general, you will want to find all properties whose types can be cast to `string`.

Comment: I see your point, but I need this for update localizeable properties in a WPF app's ViewModel class after updating the Culture.
So I just need the *real* string properties so that I can raise their PropertyChanged events.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) method of [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx):

```
GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

This will give you an array of [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) objects, one for each property.

You can check the property is a `string` property by checking that:

```
property.PropertyType == typeof(string)
```

To get the names of the properties use `property.Name`.

Comment: Sorry, but how to include a check on string properties? I dont want to get someInt in my example.

Comment: thanks, upvoted but gave DSO the checkmark for a complete copy-paste-able solution :-)

Comment: @Thomas I've updated my answer with the check for the property type.

Comment: Once you have PropertyInfo, you can check (assuming propInfo is your PropertyInfo inside your loop):

if (propInfo.GetType()==typeof(string))
{
  // eat your heart out
}

Answer (score 1):

```
var publicStringProperties = 
    from property in GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    where property.PropertyType == typeof(string)
    select property.Name;
```