# How do I export all classes and their properties as text in VS2012 without comments

Tags: c#, class, documentation

I want to create the backbone for a document that will describe all the models used in my project. Surely VS2012 must have some way for me to generate a list of all classes in a project together with attributes defined for those classes?

I looked at the ClassDiagram, but that does not contain that attributes. Ghostwriter add-on only created the `///` auto comments above each class method or attribute. We also do not want to add XML comments for every class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this also by yourself by using reflection. It gives you more freedom as you can format output as you want.

Following code would output all classes and they properties:

```
 public void ListClasses()
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var allTypes = assembly.GetTypes();
            Debug.WriteLine("Namespace \t Class \t Property \t Type");
            foreach(var type in allTypes)
            {
                var props = type.GetProperties();
                foreach(var prop in props)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", type.Namespace, type.Name, prop.Name, prop.PropertyType));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! This has saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Your answer together with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4247488/67249 answer gave me the tools to quickly document our large project.

Answer (score 0):

This code prints all the types and memberinfo (constructors, events, fields, methods, and properties) of the current assembly

```
Assembly thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
StringBuilder OutputText ;

OutputText = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Type t in thisAssembly.GetTypes())
{
    OutputText.AppendLine("\nPUBLIC MEMBERS FOR:" + t.FullName);
    MemberInfo[] Members = t.GetMembers(); 

    foreach (MemberInfo NextMember in Members) 
    { 
        OutputText.AppendLine("\n\t" + NextMember.DeclaringType + " " + NextMember.MemberType + "  " + NextMember.Name); 
    } 
}
Console.WriteLine(OutputText);
```

For more details about instrospection see [**http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55710/Reflection-in-NET**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55710/Reflection-in-NET)