# Check if any object property contains string

Tags: c#

I have a list of `UserInformation`

```
List<UserInformation> ui = new List<UserInformation>();
```

The UserInformation object looks like this;

```
public class UserInformation
{
    public UserInformation()
    {
    }

    public UserInformation(UserInformation u)
    {
        this.Id = u.Id;
        this.parentId = u.parentId;
        this.Name = u.Name;
        this.Title = u.Title;
        this.Department = u.Department;
        this.Image = u.Image;
        this.Parent = u.Parent;
        this.Username = u.Username;
        this.Company = u.Company;
        this.Initials = u.Initials;
        this.Disabled = u.Disabled;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? parentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
}
```

Is there some way to check if any of these properties, contains a specific Word? Lets say ".test"?

**Update**

I kinda want to avoid something like

```
!new[] { ".ext", ".test", ".admin" }.Any(c => ui.Title.ToLower().Contains(c))
!new[] { ".ext", ".test", ".admin" }.Any(c => ui.Department.ToLower().Contains(c))
!new[] { ".ext", ".test", ".admin" }.Any(c => ui.Company.ToLower().Contains(c))
!new[] { ".ext", ".test", ".admin" }.Any(c => ui.Username.ToLower().Contains(c))
```

Comment: `obj.property == ".test"`???

Comment: I think he means something like reflection, getting properties and comparing those with string type to ".test". Right?

Comment: I want to check if the entire `UserInformation` object contains ".test", it can be any of the properties that contains the word

Comment: [Here's a start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718863/how-to-iterate-all-public-string-properties-in-a-net-class), I'm sure you can work the rest out yourself.

Comment: you want to compare the property name or its value?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani the value

Comment: @PeterHansen - While the three answers using Runtime Reflection are correct and will work - it looks like you might be trying to do this on a large list of all users. If this is the case this could be really slow. Look into t4 templates or search engine if this is the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this method using reflection to get all properties that contain your text:

```
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> PropertiesThatContainText<T>(T obj, string text, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.Ordinal)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
       .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string) && p.CanRead);
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
    {
        string propVal = (string)prop.GetValue(obj, null);
        if (String.Equals(text, propVal, comparison)) yield return prop;
    }
}
```

If you just want to know if there was at least one property:

```
bool anyPropertyContainsText = PropertiesThatContainText(yourUserInfo, ".test").Any();
```

But in general i would avoid using reflection wherever possible. Instead create a method in `UserInformation` that checks the relevant properties explicitly. Or just check it where you have to know it. A little verbose but readable and everyone will understand your code including yourself.

Comment: I am wondering how this method can be changed to find all elements of a List whose string properties contain the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use runtime Reflection as DavidG pointed out;

[How to iterate all "public string" properties in a .net class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718863/how-to-iterate-all-public-string-properties-in-a-net-class)

but this will be slow if you are doing this for a large dataset (i.e. all users) - In this case a better way would be to use T4 templates to generate the code;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

or to perform this in either a database (if thats where the info comes from) or create an index and use a 'search' engine like lucene

https://lucene.apache.org/