# Foreach String variable (not Value) in a List<>

Tags: string, list, linq, foreach, bindinglist

Getting a lot of answers on how to find string values in a list of strings.
But not String Types in a list and then query those strings. I am trying to return every Listitem that has any sting value the user types in, like a global search. I'd like to use Linq, but old school is good too.

My research bottom of post.

I have a Garage Class that contains a list of many different variable types.

```
[Serializable()]
public class Garage 
{
public static BindingList<Vechicle> VechicleList = new 
BindingList<Vechicle>();
```

Based on the Vechicle Class below:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Vechicle
{
//String formatting for Useraccount section and main list
private string HeaderStringFormat = "{0,-8} {1,-15} {2,-15} {3,-10:c} {4,-10} 
{5,-5} {6,-10}";
public string Make { get; set; }
public string Model { get; set; }
public string Color { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
public double KilometerReading { get; set; }
public Image Pic { get; set; } = Properties.Resources.Default;
public bool IsSold { get; set; } = false;
public DateTime DateSold { get; set; }
```

I want to query this list for all String Variables and then query those variables by the query string as below. I don't want to go through every item with trycatch if possible.

Here is my code so far:

```
  private void Txt_Search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = Txt_Search.Text.Trim();
        List<Vechicle> SearchList = new List<Vechicle>();
        foreach (Vechicle v in Garage.VechicleList.Where()
       //Stuck here unsure how to get all values of strings to then query
   }
```

Stuff I've looked at, but cant seem to find an answer

c# - Cleanest Way to Find a Match In a List - Stack Overflow

foreach item in a list that matches a string - Google Search

c# - How to compare values foreach inside a foreach - Stack Overflow

c# - Foreach with a where clause? - Stack Overflow

foreach where - Google Search

c# - How can I loop through a List and grab each item? - Stack Overflow

foreach string where in list - Google Search

foreach string variable in eachstring of a list - Google Search

foreach string in list - Google Search

foreach string - Google Search

c# - Finding Class Elements in a List of Classes - Stack Overflow

search for strings in a class c# - Google Search

search for strings in a class - Google Search

Comment: Do you mean enumerating through the `Make`, `Model`, and `Color` properties since they are the only properties that are `string`'s? If so, you'll need reflection to do this. This sort of thing is more for dynamic languages, not statically typed and compiled languages like C#.

Comment: To try simplify, I want to reiterate over all Vechicles in the VechicleList and only query those items that are strings for a certain any text string entered. Without causing errors.

Comment: oh just got that.. yes, just the string values. For example if car name is Toyota and user searches "toyota" they will match to the Vechicle item. but if that "Toyota" exists as another list item, return that to. OH and if Toyota was a color it would return as well

Comment: Perhaps this answer may point you in the right direction? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718863/how-to-iterate-all-public-string-properties-in-a-net-class

Comment: Where would `"Toyota"` be found on a `Vehicle`? In the `Make` or `Model` fields? `Garage.VechicleList.Where(v => v.Make.Equals(query))`?

Comment: Yes, but i would need to query every string item in the class, Manually. Because i want to search all String Variables in the Vehicle Class, even if its not necessary.

Comment: Yes, you would. Or else you would have to find all of the Properties of the class that are of type string using reflection as @alec suggested.  But that will end up being more verbose and is really only useful if you were querying unknown types.

As @alec suggested, just do `Garage.VechicleList.Where(v => v.Make.Equals(query) || v.Model.Equals(query) || v.Color.Equals(query))`

Comment: foreach Vechicle in the VechicleList
{
If it has a String Variable what is it? Does it match the users TextBox.text String?, yes, then pull that Vechicle out into a new list.
}

Comment: OK. Thank you. Reflection sounds interesting. OK ill do what is suggested, was just hoping for a quicker easier or better way

Comment: I think the link given by @CameronAavik will definitely help you.

Comment: Yes it definitely does :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718863/how-to-iterate-all-public-string-properties-in-a-net-class

Comment: Garage.VechicleList.Where(v => v.Make.Equals(query) || v.Model.Equals(query) || v.Color.Equals(query)) - This is very nice too. Thanks @bigtlb

Comment: You may want to use `Contains` instead of `Equals` and you may want to do `IndexOf() > 0` instead of `Contains` to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys
explicitly for this link [How to iterate all "public string" properties in a .net class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718863/how-to-iterate-all-public-string-properties-in-a-net-class)

```
private string[] GetPublicStringProperties()
{
return this.GetType()
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    .Select(pi => pi.Name)
    .ToArray();
}
```

@Cameron Aavik :)

Comment: This loops through the names of the properties, not the values (which is what you want)

Comment: It is really a bad idea to use Reflection when you already know the field names. And why not do `ToString` on the non-`string` properties or fields?